# How do I check rate of insertion into Cassandra using OpsCenter?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0

I am using OpsCenter 6.5.0 version.ANd I have to find out row insertion rate in Cassandra like by which rate rows are being inserted into Cassaandra table.

So how Can I find this rate of insertion using OpsCenter?

Answer (score 2):

All the OpsCenter performance metrics are covered in the docs here:

https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/6.5/opsc/online_help/opscPerformanceMetrics_c.html

I would start with the cluster wide ones like "Write Requests" and then you can drill down to table level metrics like "TBL: Local Writes"